# Xcode 9.1 Archive error

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

My project is building and archiving fine before. Now it can only build and run in Simulator and device. Archiving fails, hence I can not submit another Test Flight build. This has been tying me up for 4 days now and my company is expecting another Test Flight build, but I can't deliver due to this error.

[image: Xcode error] 
Xcode version: Version 9.1 (9B55)

Below is my `pod env`:

````
    ### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.4.0.beta.2
        Ruby : ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]
    RubyGems : 2.7.0
        Host : Mac OS X 10.13.1 (17B48)
       Xcode : 9.1 (9B55)
         Git : git version 2.13.6 (Apple Git-96)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ d7f61ecea08fb9967efdc454815f49e7196841aa
```

### Installation Source

```
Executable Path: /usr/local/bin/pod
```

### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.1
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.3.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0
```

### Podfile

```ruby
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

def default_pods

    # Networking, Keychain and Alert
    pod 'AFNetworking'
    pod 'SSKeychain'
    pod 'SAMKeychain'
    pod 'RMUniversalAlert'

    #Map
    pod 'GoogleMaps'

    #Dates
    pod 'DateTools', '1.7.0'
    pod 'MTDates'

    #Activity Indicator
    pod 'SVProgressHUD'

    #Data and Mapping
    pod 'EasyMapping', '~> 0.16.1'
    pod 'MagicalRecord'

    #Debug Mode
    #pod 'Reveal-iOS-SDK', :configurations => ['Debug']

    #Keyboard
    pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
    pod 'TSValidatedTextField'

    #Paralax Navigation Bar
    pod 'GKFadeNavigationController'

    #Segment
    pod 'Analytics', '3.5.5'
    pod 'libPusher', git: 'https://github.com/pusher/libPusher.git', branch: 'push-notifications'
    pod 'Mixpanel'#, '3.0.7'

    #Phone Number Parser
    pod 'libPhoneNumber-iOS', '~> 0.8'

    #Textfield Animation
    pod 'SkyFloatingLabelTextField', '~> 2.0.0'

    #Smooch (customer care chat)
    pod 'Smooch'

    # Crashlytics
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'

    # 2fa pin code entry
    pod 'PopupDialog'#, '~> 0.6'

    # etc
    pod 'MZFormSheetPresentationController'
end

target 'Upsales CRM Mobile Edition' do
    default_pods
end

target 'Upsales CRM Mobile Edition AdHoc' do
    default_pods
end

target 'Upsales CRM Mobile Edition Internal AdHoc' do
    default_pods
end
```
````

Comment: Have you ever tried to delete DerivedData?

Comment: Yes I did try deleting the DerivedData, as well as removing the pods, then pod install/update, putting them back in, then pod install/update.

Comment: What is your version of cocoapods ? Did you tried to upgrade DateTools to the last version ?

Comment: @AntonMalmygin See my updated `pod env`. I updated DateTools, but then the next pod will get the same error as in the screenshot, i.e. `AFNetworking`, `GKFadeNavigationController`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check whether some files of UIKit framework was changed or not accidentally. 
And then you can try to replace UIKit framework in Xcode folder with a new UIKit framework.
Or not, you can try to remove and install Xcode again. 
Of course, after then you have to remove DerivedData and rebuild.

I hope it would help you. Good luck.

Comment: Deleting Xcode and reinstalling it now allows me to archive. Whew! What a bummer.

Answer (score 1):

try **clean(command+shift+k) then archive** .if that not help close the xcode  **clear the derived data**  then  open project **clean** and archive

Comment: Have done done many times already, but still can't archive. Same error as above.